# Automatic Symfony protocol for authetifying users does not work

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

First of all, sorry for my bad English. If anything is incomprehensible, ask me what I meant.

Now to my question:

Currently I set up one of my first symfony projects and I want to implement an user-managment-system (like: login, register, logout. You know what I mean). First Symfony provides a automatic System which generates an user database and src structure ([Source](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)). I did this and everything works fine until this point. But now, I've wanted to add an automatic authenticator. To realize this, I followed this instruction: [Link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) which also generates automatic all classes and stuff. The problem is now that if I try to login, nothing happends and the dev-profiler only says

> Authenticator does not support the request

So how can I fix that?

---

Here is my code:

- SecurityController: https://hastebin.com/tiruyoteco.php
- LoginAuth. https://hastebin.com/abewapanod.php
- Security.yaml https://hastebin.com/upesewodow.yaml
- login.html.twig https://hastebin.com/gewifaxozi.csharp

---

I hope you can help me to fix that problem.
Greetings

Comment: Check `bin/console debug:container`. Is `LoginFormAuthenticator` registered as a service?